# Proving a thermodynamic relation between $(\partial H/\partial T)_p$ and $(\partial U/\partial T)_V$

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

(This question is taken from Problem 1.1(b) of the book Chemical Thermodynamics: Principles and Applications.)$\require{begingroup} \begingroup \newcommand{\pd}[3]{\left(\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}\right)_{\!#3}}$

> Prove $$\pd HTp = \pd UTV + \left[ V - \pd HpT \right] \pd pTV. \tag{1}$$

First, I expressed $H$ as  $U + PV$, and took the partial derivative against $T$, keeping pressure constant:

$$\pd HTp = \pd UTp + p\pd VTp \tag{2}$$

Expressing $U$ as a function of $(T, V)$:

$$\pd UTp = \pd UTV + \pd UVT \pd VTp \tag{3}$$

Using the well-known identity that $$\pd pVT \pd TpV \pd VTp = -1, \tag{4}$$

$$\pd UVT \pd VTp = -\pd UpT \pd pTV = \left[ V - \pd UpT - V\pd ppT \right]\pd pTV \tag{5}$$

This, of course, means that

$$\pd HTp = \pd UTV + \left[ V - \pd HpT \right]\pd pTV + p\pd VTp \tag{6}$$

Based on my working, there is an additional $$p\pd VTp$$ term. Is my working incorrect? I can’t find my mistake.$\endgroup$

Comment: You might want to make a new command for a partial derivative to save yourself some pain. I can give you an example in a while...

Comment: put at the start of your post: `$\require{begingroup} \begingroup \newcommand{\pd}[3]{\left(\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}\right)_{\!#3}}$` and at the end of your post `$\endgroup$`... and between those lines you can now use `$\pd{V}{T}{p}$` (or even `\pd VTp` although I don't recommend making the latter a habit, unless you understand why it works without braces).

Comment: I also recommend display style mathematics, i.e. `$$ ... $$` or if really necessary `$\displaystyle ...$`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what display style is? I’m not too familiar with it.

Comment: I (very cautiously) think the question might be incorrect. My working out of the RHS (albeit by a different approach) is yielding an inconsistency too. Can someone check and confirm?

Comment: I believe you make an error when writing the expression for $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p$

Comment: @orthocresol Why does it work without braces?  And why did you use `{\!#3}` instead of just `{#3}` in defining the command?  I tried it both with and without the added `\!` in my TeX editor, and it gave the same results both ways (for both with and without braces).

Comment: @theorist Truthfully, I don't fully understand it myself... but it has something to do with how TeX scans for arguments. Usually it just reads in one thing at a time (either a letter or a control sequence like `\alpha`) and treats that as an argument. Grouping several things together with curly braces allows you to pass more than one character at a time. That also means that if you only want a single-character argument, it's unnecessary to enclose it in braces (although having braces is a lot more familiar for most people) [...]

Comment: [...] the `\!` is just cosmetic. You probably know it is a "negative space". I find that without it, the subscripted value is too far away from the brackets; but that's just personal preference, really. If you're interested in the braces, there's always Knuth's good old TeXBook which I think explains this behaviour very carefully.

Comment: @orthocresol I really like this -- avoiding braces is very nice for efficiency.   I might post a question on TeX SE asking if there is any chance it could cause problems (assuming you hold to the one character restriction).  If I do I'll link it here.

Comment: @orthocresol:  See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525656/is-it-a-problem-to-implement-a-user-defined-command-without-using-braces

Comment: @theorist, I should have but didn’t warn you that it would 99% be a duplicate of something. TeX.SE has been going strong for many years and has serious experts over there, including multiple people involved in LaTeX kernel development. Consequently, nearly everything a rookie like me might think of asking has been asked. :)

Comment: @orthocresol  That's OK.  I did search TeX SE extensively (using various search terms) before posting and was unable to find a similar question, so posting was in fact useful because it both gave me an answer an a link to a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup \newcommand{\pd}[3]{\left(\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}\right)_{\!#3}}$

I would start from

$$ dH = \pd HTp dT + \pd HpT dp$$

This gives rise to

$$ \pd HTV = \pd HTp  + \pd HpT \pd pTV$$

in which you can recognize some components of the solution. Since

$$dH = dU +PdV + VdP $$

so that

$$ \pd HTV = \pd UTV  + V \pd pTV$$

it follows that

$$ \pd UTV  + V \pd pTV = \pd HTp  + \pd HpT \pd pTV$$

which is readily rearranged to obtain the desired equation.
$\endgroup$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could I inquire where I went wrong in my incorrect proof? I’m not too sure why my first expression is wrong.

Comment: @ANZGCFlyingFalcon It looks like you flubbed the substitution of Eq 4 into Eq 3 (see the middle expression in Eq 5).

Comment: If I were to take the RHS of (5) and multiply it by (4), wouldn’t I get the LHS? (Obviously the sign would become +ve but you get what I mean.)

Comment: To get $(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p})_T$ I recommend starting from the differential form of U=H-PV and taking the derivative wrt p at constant T. I'm not sure how you arrive at your result, it is hard for me to follow.